# Updating PyQt4 Progress bar within for loop - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, progress-bar, pyqt4

I augmented [this example](https://pythonspot.com/en/qt4-progressbar/) to allow my user to know what part of the process the program is in when it is handling a RAM intensive and iterative process in a For Loop. I find that the following script works when it is just asking to print the count value and wait a few seconds, but it doesn't for more intensive functions.

```
# from https://pythonspot.com/en/qt4-progressbar/

import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSlot,SIGNAL,SLOT
import time

class QProgBar(QProgressBar):

    value = 0

    @pyqtSlot()
    def increaseValue(progressBar):
        progressBar.setValue(progressBar.value)
        progressBar.value = progressBar.value+1

# Create an PyQT4 application object.
a = QApplication(sys.argv)       

# The QWidget widget is the base class of all user interface objects in PyQt4.
w = QWidget()

# Set window title  
w.setWindowTitle("PyQT4 Progressbar @ pythonspot.com ") 

# Create progressBar. 
bar = QProgBar(w)
bar.resize(320,50)    
bar.setValue(0)


bar.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
bar.move(0,50)

label = QLabel("test",w)
label.setStyleSheet("QLabel { font-size: 20px }")
label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
label.move(0,10)

# create timer for progressBar
'''timer = QTimer()
bar.connect(timer,SIGNAL("timeout()"),bar,SLOT("increaseValue()"))
timer.start(400)'''

# Show window
w.show()

for i in range(0,100):
    print(i) 
    ### Do action
    bar.setValue(i)
    time.sleep(0.5)

sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

Is there anything I can do to make this work for more intense actions? Does anyone know of a better package for progress bars that I can insert within a for loop easily?

I am new to GUI development in general, and I really only need simple UI's.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer :)

Answer (score 1):

Qt will not update your UI until you give control back to the event loop, that is, until your for loop ends. You can make the event loop update the UI by calling `processEvents` like this:

```
for i in range(0,100):
    print(i) 
    ### Do action
    bar.setValue(i)
    a.processEvents()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```